# kotlin: bounds not allowed on typealias type parameters

Tags: generics, kotlin

I am trying to have the following type:

```
typealias Graph<T:Comparable<T>> = Map<T, List<T>>
```

I get an error saying bounds are not allowed on typealias'ed types.

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but if you want a way to constrain the type of map that can be passed or stored in a property, this is the simplest way I can think of. Make a wrapper class that delegates to the map so it can be a map itself:

```
class Graph<T: Comparable<T>> (private val map: Map<T, List<T>>): Map<T, List<T>> by map {
    override fun toString() = map.toString()
    // You can use the IDE to generate equals and hashcode out of the map property
}
```

You can also make some functions to make the usage familiar:

```
fun <T:Comparable<T>> graphOf(): Graph<T> = Graph(emptyMap())
fun <T:Comparable<T>> graphOf(pair: Pair<T, List<T>>): Graph<T> = Graph(mapOf(pair))
fun <T:Comparable<T>> graphOf(vararg pairs: Pair<T, List<T>>): Graph<T> = Graph(mapOf(*pairs))
```

Usage:

```
val graph: Graph<String> = graphOf("x" to listOf("y", "z"))
```

It's not as nice as a typealias would be if typealiasing could do that, because you must always wrap a map to be able to pass it as a Graph. You could also create a convenience function for wrapping a map for use when passing it as a parameter:

```
fun <T:Comparable<T>> Map<T, List<T>>.toGraph(): Graph<T> = 
        if (this is Graph) this else Graph(this)
```

Comment: I suggest not relying on `equals` generated by IDE, because it violates `Map.equals` contract, according to which maps are equal if they represent the same mappings. Consider implementing `equals` manually: `override fun equals(other: Any?) = this === other || other is Graph<*> && map == other.map || map == other`

Comment: You’re right. The IDE version would insist on the class type matching. Hashcode should just be `map.hashcode`

Comment: I don't get it. What's wrong with the class type matching in equals contract?

Comment: Different classes implementing Map are supposed to be equal if they contain the same contents, even though they are not the same class. If you use the IDE’s feature to generate the equals function, it will only declare members of the same class as equal.